# Changing value on keydown event refreshes page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery to make a calculator. The issue is that on keydown, I call the calculate function which calculates and returns the value. However, if I change the value in the textbox, and press keydown again, the page refreshes and everything is blank.

I don't want the page to refresh, if the user changes the value in the textbox. It should call the calculate function again and return and display the new result.

This is the code:

```
lgpm.keydown(function(event){

            var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
            if(keycode == '13'){
                if (formValidate()){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                calculateMet();
                }
            }
            event.stopPropagation();
        });
```

Comment: How does your HTML look (including `<form`> tag)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `event.preventDefault()` method needs to be called whenever the enter key is pressed - else it will submit the form - try this

```
lgpm.keydown(function(event){

        var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
        if(keycode == '13'){
            event.preventDefault();
            if (formValidate()){
                return false;
            }
            else {
            calculateMet();
            }
        }
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
```

Comment: This code didn't work. It doesn't refresh the page, but it doesn't call the calculate function either on keydown the second time.

Comment: Okay, I just realized it works. But it only takes the new value of the textbox which is being keypressed/keydown-ed [that is the last textbox of the form which the user inputs]. IF I change the value of other textboxes, and then press keydown on the last textbox, the calculate function isn't called i.e. I'm assuming the new values of the textbox isn't being retrieved.

Comment: Can you post your full code on JSFiddle.net perhaps ? It will make it a lot easier to debug ... Why have you got the stopPropagation method in there ?

Comment: Here is the code on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ak4qn/  I'm not sure why javascript is not working there.

Comment: @fuz3d You had quite a few errors in there ... i have updated it .... http://jsfiddle.net/Ak4qn/1/

Comment: Thank you so much. Your help was much appreciated. But what were those errors?

Comment: @fuz3d You had `nbnm.attr..` instead of `$('#nbnm').attr..` and also the same on keydown - you need to use the jQuery selector first to apply jQuery methods

Comment: Ahh.. thank you for pointing out. Actually I had declared them on DOM ready and then removed them, not realizing that I had called the declaration elsewhere in the code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try adding event.stopPropagation() after event.preventDefault()

Answer (score 0):

Change your body to:

```
if(keycode == '13'){                                                                                              
   if (formValidate()){                                                                                          
      event.preventDefault();                                                                                   
   } else {                                                                                                      
      calculateGravelMetric();                                                                                   
   }                                                                                                             
}                                                                                                                 
return false;
```

... thus the default handling will always be prevented